# Spring ResourceBundle not found for base name

Tags: java, spring, maven

I'm having problems taking the message values to a properties file.

I'm using intelliJ IDEA and i have a package

```
com.test.messages
```

and inside I have the messages.properties file.

Here is my xml

```
   <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="com.test.messages.messages"/>
    </bean>
```

When I restart the server this is the WARNING i get

```
WARNING: ResourceBundle [com.test.messages.messages] not found for MessageSource: Can't find bundle for base name com.test.messages.messages, locale en_US
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you use maven for the build?

Comment: YEs, i'm using maven

Answer (score 1):

Do not keep properties in packages.
Resources directory is a standart place to keep internal properties.

```
/src/main/resources
```

or

```
/src/test/resources
```

If you want to keep properties separated from the project - use something this kind of spring configuration:

```
<bean id="props" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="ignoreResourceNotFound" value="true"/>
    <property name="localOverride" value="true"/>
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath*:messages.properties</value>
            <value>file:messages.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

So you'd be able to override internal properties with external (don't forget to add the to a classpath using -cp).

Anyway the declaration of the been will look like this:

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="${property.name}"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Idea or Eclipes - you'd should be able to create a resource directory.

Answer (score 0):

you should have a file in your project as such:

```
src\main\resources\com\test\messages.properties
```

Comment: Well, I don't I only have one src folder and my packages are in it. I have resources folder but it is under web

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not IDEA expert, I know that resources such as .property files placed in the source code hierarchy are copied to the classpath when using the IDE alone.  However, if you use maven, then it takes over the build and whatever is in the java path is not copied by default. You have to place all your classpath resources in `src\main\resources` and under whatever hierarchy mirrors the package name to have the same result.  So in your case :

```
src\main\resources\com\test\messages\messages.properties
```

and maven will copy it properly

Comment: I do not have resources or main folder under src. I've used eclipse and I know that there is like that:
src/main/java
src/main/resources

However, in idea under src i have only my packages.

Comment: if you use maven you should, otherwise you have to override the maven configuration to tailor it according to your needs. Maven works in a convention-over-configuration fashion so some things like directory structure are pre-configured

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old question, but let me drop my solution :)

Source folder (`resources` is not package):

```
/src/main/java/
              somepackage/abc.java
/src/main/resources/
              messages.properties
```

Eclipse default output java build path:

```
myProject/build/classes
```

Eclipse default deploy path:

```
WEB-INF/classes
```

My project's spring context XML file path:

```
/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/context.xml
```

Inject resource bundles,

```
<bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
   <property name="basenames" value="messages"/>
</bean>
```

As Azee said keeping properties in package is not encourage. In case, `messages.properties` is in `resources` package as below:

```
/src/resources/messages.properties
```

context.xml should be like:

```
 <property name="basenames" value="resources/messages"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this error like this:

AppConfig.java:

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
public ResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource() {

    var source = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
    source.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
    source.setUseCodeAsDefaultMessage(true);

    return source;
   }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
<resources>
<resource>
    <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
        <include>**/application*.yml</include>
        <include>**/messages*.properties</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

ServiceExtController.java:

```
private String getLibelleService(TypeService typeService) {
return messageSource.getMessage("service.name." + typeService.toString().toLowerCase(), null, Locale.FRENCH);
```

}

src/main/resources:

--> i18n/message.properties